# bind pirobox with new created elements

Tags: jquery, dom, live

I'm having a problem with priroBox a jquery plugin similar to lightbox.
the problem is priroBox does not recognize new created elements in DOM

this is the code to call birobox

```
$().piroBox_ext({
piro_speed : 700,
    bg_alpha : 0.5,
    piro_scroll : true 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code after generating links.

$(document).find('a.pirobox_gal').pirobox_ext();